# How to get emacs indent correctly inside of initialization list in c++?

Tags: c++11, emacs

I want to initialize an array in this way:

```
int arr
{
    3,
    4
};
```

But my emacs misindents it to:

```
int arr
{
    3,
        4
        };
```

Please note a missing "=". I am using an initializer list here and this syntax is correct.

Comment: What version of Emacs and what OS?  Also, does it make any difference running "emacs -Q"?

Answer (score 1):

Using a more recent version of emacs might help. The indentation of braced initializer list was improved in https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24431.

Emacs 26.1 indents the same code as

```
int arr
    {
        3,
        4
    };
```

which is not all the way there but at least better.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative I would like to suggest [clang-format with Emacs](https://github.com/sonatard/clang-format)

There are plenty of [options](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) you can play with.

These options are to be defined in a *.clang-format* file (in your home directory or in your C++ project root directories)

Answer (score 0):

And what about nesting initializer lists, with trailing commas, which are now supported (c++11)?
Say I was building JSON. (cpprestsdk)
what I see:

```
    using JsonValue = web::json::value;
    auto json = JsonValue::object({
            {"a", JsonValue("v")},
            {"b", JsonValue::array({
                        {JsonValue(1)},
                        {JsonValue::object({
                                    {},
                                    {},
                                        })},
                        {JsonValue(3)},
                            })},
            {"c", JsonValue::object()},
                });
```

what I want to see

```
    auto json = JsonValue::object({
        {"a", JsonValue("v")},
        {"b", JsonValue::array({
            {JsonValue(1)},
            {JsonValue::object({
                {},
                {},
            })},
            {JsonValue(3)},
        })},
        {"c", JsonValue::object()},
    });
```

Assuming I prefer starting with Allman/BSD basic formatting...

Comment: Wait a minute.... I just tried it without the parens (only the braces). And emacs already handles it exactly the way I want... Interesting...